# Nginx does not route traffic to Node js server in AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Using `ElasticBeanstalk` to deploy an NodeJS web application. I have the `Nginx` config file like below:

```
events {}
http {
  server { # simple reverse-proxy
    listen       80;
    # pass requests for dynamic content
    location / {
      proxy_pass      http://localhost:5000;
    }
  }
}
```

I have the node server starting at port `5000`.

I see the `Nginx` seems starting ok as well:

```
2021/08/25 16:16:28.573953 [INFO] Executing instruction: start proxy with new configuration
2021/08/25 16:16:28.573976 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /var/proxy/staging/nginx/nginx.conf
2021/08/25 16:16:28.678857 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c cp -rp /var/proxy/staging/nginx/* /etc/nginx
2021/08/25 16:16:28.698889 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf nginx.service
2021/08/25 16:16:28.717393 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl daemon-reload
2021/08/25 16:16:28.824685 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl reset-failed
2021/08/25 16:16:28.829180 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf nginx.service
2021/08/25 16:16:28.834724 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active nginx.service
2021/08/25 16:16:28.838286 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start nginx.service
```

But when I click the `ElasticBeanstalk` link, I see it goes to the default AWS Nginx page with title `Welcome to nginx on Amazon Linux!`

Did I miss anything in the config?

Comment: I guess this article would be helpful for your question answer [Configuring the reverse proxy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html)

Comment: you don't need to configure nginx, by default AWS supports it, try to upload the code without this config